# Coffeescript: Check whether value in json

Tags: json, coffeescript

To check whether value is available in json. I am using following code

```
        $scope.bindRoles.push
            Name: "Name"
            Editable: if item in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser then true else false // here i am checking if item is present in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser then set value of Editable as true.
```

where, $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser = ["Admin", "Role1", "Role2"]

My requirement is, i want to check one more thing in that if statement. Either item or "Admin" is present in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser then set value of Editable as true.

How can i do that?

Please help,
Thanks

Comment: just take out the redundant statement at the end: `Editable: item in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like?

```
Editable: if ('Admin' in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser or item in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser) then yes else no
```

I am not sure what you mean when you say .. Either item or "Admin". Are you saying that if rolesOfLoggedUser is not empty = has an item or ? What is item here?

then maybe:

```
Editable: if ('Admin' in $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser or $scope.rolesOfLoggedUser.length > 0) then yes else no
```

But if you want to know if that there is just an item, then wouldn't any value in that array be "editable", therefore you wouldn't have to explicitly test for "Admin", correct?